# How do I pass an array between two functions in python?

Tags: python, arrays, function

I wish to pass three arrays : `xLinespace`, `yLinespace` and `zLinespace` from the function `cubicSplineInterpolate` to the function `trajectoryMover`. However I am not sure how to achieve this using python. After passing the arrays to the second function, I intend to iterate through each array simulataneously in order to alter the position of a robot. Do I need to set the arrays as arguments in each function?

```
class example_application:

    def cubicSplineInterpolate(self, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis):

        m=1
        xLinespace=[]
        yLinespace=[]
        zLinespace=[]
        while m<len(x_axis):
            for t in np.arange(m-1,m,1/float(100)):
                xLinespace.append(self.func(x_axis[m-1],x_axis[m],t,U[m-1],U[m],m-1,m))
                yLinespace.append(self.func(y_axis[m-1],y_axis[m],t,V[m-1],V[m],m-1,m))
                zLinespace.append(self.func(z_axis[m-1],z_axis[m],t,W[m-1],W[m],m-1,m))
            m=m+1

    def trajectoryMover(self):
        newPose = Pose()
        xLinespace=[]
        yLinespace=[]
        zLinespace=[]
        x_axis = [0.01, 0.02, 0.033, 0.0044, 0.0001, 0.10]
        y_axis = [0.002, 0.00033, 0.1014, 0.01512, 0.14316, 0.015143]
        z_axis = [0.003, 0.2124, 0.15417, 0.15615, 0.01241, 0.151561]
        self.cubicSplineInterpolate(x_axis,y_axis,z_axis)
        print(self.cubicSplineInterpolate.xLinespace)

        for x, y, z in zip(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis):

            newPose.position.x = x
            newPose.position.y = y
            newPose.position.z = z
            newPose.orientation.x = -0.907106781172
            newPose.orientation.y = -0.0707106781191
            newPose.orientation.z = 2.59734823723e-06
            newPose.orientation.w = -2.59734823723e-06
            self.set_position_cartesian.publish(newPose)
            rospy.loginfo(newPose)
            rospy.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, and there's far too much code here. But if you need to pass items to functions, then yes of course they need to be parameters.

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up my terminology. I meant, do I need to set xLinespace, yLinespace and zLinespace as arguments for each function?

Comment: why don't you use `self.xLinespace`, so you can share them between different class functions.

Comment: So within both functions, it would be: self.xLinespace.append(self.func(x_axis[m-1],x_axis[m],t,U[m-1],U[m],m-1,m))

Comment: I'm assuming you're missing some code, as this is ROS there is usually a subscribe and then a callback function?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: if `trajectoryMover` calls `cubicSplineInterpolate`

class example_application:

```
def cubicSplineInterpolate(self, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis):

    m=1
    xLinespace=[]
    yLinespace=[]
    zLinespace=[]
    while m<len(x_axis):
        for t in np.arange(m-1,m,1/float(100)):
            xLinespace.append(self.func(x_axis[m-1],x_axis[m],t,U[m-1],U[m],m-1,m))
            yLinespace.append(self.func(y_axis[m-1],y_axis[m],t,V[m-1],V[m],m-1,m))
            zLinespace.append(self.func(z_axis[m-1],z_axis[m],t,W[m-1],W[m],m-1,m))
        m=m+1

        return(xLinespace, yLinespace, zLinespace)

def trajectoryMover(self):
    newPose = Pose()
    x_axis = [0.01, 0.02, 0.033, 0.0044, 0.0001, 0.10]
    y_axis = [0.002, 0.00033, 0.1014, 0.01512, 0.14316, 0.015143]
    z_axis = [0.003, 0.2124, 0.15417, 0.15615, 0.01241, 0.151561]
    xLinespace, yLinespace, zLinespace = self.cubicSplineInterpolate(x_axis,y_axis,z_axis)
    print(self.cubicSplineInterpolate.xLinespace)

    for x, y, z in zip(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis):

        newPose.position.x = x
        newPose.position.y = y
        newPose.position.z = z
        newPose.orientation.x = -0.907106781172
        newPose.orientation.y = -0.0707106781191
        newPose.orientation.z = 2.59734823723e-06
        newPose.orientation.w = -2.59734823723e-06
        self.set_position_cartesian.publish(newPose)
        rospy.loginfo(newPose)
        rospy.sleep(1)
```

Also note (although not super important): I believe PEP8 says functions should be underscore separated i.e. trajectory_mover and cubic_spline_interpolate()

Comment: But they don't need to be parameters in the cubicSplineInterpolate function?

Comment: No because that's where you are creating them

Comment: No it's the other way round; trajectoryMover calls cubicSplineInterpolate

Comment: OH! Sorry, I misunderstood. Fixed it.